# Qt Creator 3.1.2 (Qt5) not highlighting typedefs defined with keyword 'using' (C++11)

Tags: c++11, qt-creator

If I use

```
typedef itk::Image<unsigned char , 3> itkVolumeType;
```

all the typedefs are highlighted in a different color. But if I use C++11

```
using itkVolumeType = itk::Image<unsigned char , 3>;
```

highlighting no longer works.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I'm using CMake.

Comment: If you think it's a bug, have you considered reporting it to the Qt folks?

Comment: I'm unsure wether or not it's a bug. But I've followed your advice and submitted a bug. Let's see... https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13182